# How to deal with invalid "editing" of a response

Tags: support

One of my answers to a question was "edited" by another user.  The "editing" consisted in inserting a hyphen in one of the words I had used, and "replacing" some other words with the *identical* spellings.  What should I do in such circumstances?

Comment: You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44618462/revisions)? The user converted a few parts of the text to use inline code formatting to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

If it stays in the suggested edits queue, simply reject it. The owner of a post has the highest privilege to edit it, and approve or reject edit suggestions.

If the edit is already applied, let it go. There's no need to intervene a meaningless edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you feel the edit conflicts with your intent and does not improve it in any way, you can roll it back to the pre-edit version of the post.

However, if you find even *parts* of the edit are helpful, consider re-editing the post to undo whatever changes you don't like while leaving the helpful parts.